# Configuring firebase for a flutter project leads to error message: Invoked Dart programs must have a 'main' function defined

Tags: flutter, firebase, initialization

When configuring firebase for a flutter project I receive this error message:

"Invoked Dart programs must have a 'main' function defined:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program
Invoked Dart programs must have a 'main' function defined:
[https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program"](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program%22)

I never had this before and have no idea where it comes from. Any ideas?

I have tried to run the commands from my command line on windows, from the terminal in VSCode, and also from the FlutterFireCLI.exe.

What I did,

- create a flutter project using `flutter create`.
- ran `firebase login`
- ran `flutterfire configure` and this does not work, although it worked for previous projects

Edit:

My main.dart =

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit 2:

It seems that more flutterfire commands result in the same error message, same goes for flutterfire --version.

Comment: can you share your main.dart code

Comment: I edited the main thread, it's the basic project, I opened a new one to test this

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android check step no 3 on this link once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

I should have ran `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli` before running `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli` . Otherwise the FlutterFireCLI would not find the correct dependencies.